# Excel Sumifs to where "sum_range" is the product of two ranges?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get this line of code to work:

- =SUMIFS($A$30:$A$5141*$B$30:$B$5141,$C$30:$C$5141,1)

But Excel doesn't accept this as a valid formula.

However, if I create a dummy "SPILL range," I can get this to work.

I.e. if I put this code in cell "D1"

- =$A$30:$A$5141*$B$30:$B$5141

Then this SUMIFS works fine:

- =SUMIFS(D1#,$C$30:$C$5141,1)

Why don't SUMIFS work with dynamically created ranges? Other Excel functions seem to work okay.

Is there any way to compress the SUMIFS into one formula without using a help column or a helper SPILL function?

I'm using Excel 365.

Comment: `$A$30:$A$5141*$B$30:$B$5141` resolves to an `array`, not a `range`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all functions that take a range will also take an array - the [VBA documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.sumifs#:%7E:text=Sum_range) makes this explicit in the case of `SUMIFS()` - the area to be summed must be a Range.

This `SUMPRODUCT()`-based formula may suit your purposes instead

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$30:$A$5141*$B$30:$B$5141)*(C30:C5141=1))
```